# How to check relays of tx?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info, blockexplorer

I believe a tx is made of an output of previous tx.
So, I also believe that all tx are traced back to tx originally created (as a mining reward).
But, in blockchain.info and blockexplorer.com, I could not find relays of tx. 
We can know only connection of addresses in tx page.

Then, I have three questions about relays of tx.
1. Is a id(hash) of tx included in next tx id?
2. Is there a way to get information of previous tx in these websites ?
3. Why do these websites hide connection of tx?

Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Block explorers dumb down information so that it is easier for the common person to read. In reality, Bitcoin is not actually how block explorers display information; addresses do not exist at the protocol level and coins are not sent from addresses to other addresses.

> 1. Is a id(hash) of tx included in next tx id?

Yes.

> 2. Is there a way to get information of previous tx in these websites ?

Yes. Most block explorers have an advanced mode that will display this information, or at least link back to the transaction outputs that are being spent. On blockchain.info, you will see a link labeled `Show Scripts & Coinbase` when you view a transaction, click that and you will see the advanced information about the transaction.

> 3. Why do these websites hide connection of tx?

Because it isn't useful to most people and is confusing.

Comment: You are kind!  Thank you!  Your answer is perfectly what I wanted:)